# Drupal 7 timestamp insert into mysql error

Tags: database

i get error when i want to insert current time to my table-field **date**,

> i get this error PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
>   format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1345724717' for column 'date'
>   at row 1: INSERT INTO {users_history} (uid, nid, points, date, reason)
>   VALUES ('31', '107', '2', '1345724717', 'session'); Array ( ) in
>   points_node_insert() (line 57 of
>   /home/www/live_project/htdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/points/points.module).

i have table like this:

```
uid int
nid int
points int
date datetime
reason enum
```

this is my query(this query works fine if i delete **date field**)

```
  $date = time();
    db_query("INSERT INTO {users_history} 
       (uid, nid, points, date, reason) VALUES 
       ('$uid', '$nid', '$points_for_post', '$date', '$reason')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'datetime' value assumes the "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" formatting, if I got it, you're trying to insert a 'timestamp'

Comment: yep you are right, changed to $date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()); and its working